# What to look for when buying a digital piano for a beginner?

Tags: piano, keyboard, digital-piano

My wife has recently started learning to play the piano and needs something at home on which to practise. I'm inclined towards a digital piano as it is more practical (Mainly space but also no tuning required and transport).

Knowing very little about pianos myself, what should I be looking for in purchasing a digital piano? At the moment she is very much a beginner, but I wouldn't want to purchase something that will limit her too soon.

Some specific questions:

- How important is the number of keys?
- What should I look for in the keys to get a good real piano feel?

What else should I look out for? Is there any reason to strongly oppose a digital piano?

Comment: In my experience as a teacher, no student who had a digital piano stayed with it. This may be correlation and not causation, but it was 100% reliable, no matter how "dedicated" the student tried to be.

Comment: My solution to the problem was inviting my piano teacher to help me pick a piano. She wouldn't even look at anything with less than 88 keys. Almost all took only two seconds for her to shake her head and say "no". Third shop had a piano where she said "that will do" :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Digital pianos really have come a long way from where they were 15 years ago, when I started playing.

I started on an unweighted 61-key touch-sensitive keyboard (touch-sensitivity is, by the way, essential, but implied on the weighted keyboards.  You cannot play classical piano music even remotely musically without touch sensitivity.  Organ music is a different story).  It's great for playing "Mary had a little lamb" and even "Fur Elise", but when you start hitting the more involved classical repertoire, you need to have weighted keys; it's simply too hard to play without the proper resistance.  It's impossible to play more advanced classical pieces on this keyboard, because you run out of keys.  The last major drawback was that it made playing on real pianos very difficult, since it doesn't let the student develop the musculature required for playing for long periods of time on a real piano (I'm only talking a half hour, here).  That's because while they're often used as such, unweighted 61-key keyboards are not designed for use by classical pianists; they're designed for use as synthesizers.  I still have this keyboard, and whenever I have to rock out a Katy Perry or a Taio Cruz, that's the instrument I turn to.

I then bought a piano, but from the sounds of it, the piano itself and the upkeep are way too expensive at the moment.  I will say that I never bothered to keep it in tune (I've tuned it maybe 3 times in 10 years), and I regret that irresponsibility every day.  That being said, it still works!  The greatest drawback is the noise level; pianos are LOUD!  With keyboards, at least, you can pop in headphones, and it'll be mostly silent (you still have to deal with the thumping of the keys, but it's tolerable).

My latest keyboard purchase was a Yamaha Portable Grand.  It's an 88-key fully weighted keyboard.  Keep in mind that fully-weighted is just what it means: it feels like a real piano and is heavy as anything (My estimate is 50-60 pounds; I feel that portable should have been in quotes on the packaging).  It sounds beautiful and never requires tuning.  This particular keyboard has something like 500 voices (which is actually useless; I never use anything except the stock piano voice, and occasionally an organ).  This is the sort of keyboard you'd want for advanced classical pieces.  The only major problem that I have with this particular keyboard is that the sustain does not last as long as in a real piano.  This leads to sloppy pedal work, which does require a little bit of concentration to adjust for.  The other minor issue is, as I mentioned before, the weight.

It's worth noting that not all fully weighted keyboards are that much of a pain; I am in particular a fan of Casio's Privia line.  They're lighter, and I wish that I had picked that one up.  I have not played with them enough to be able to comment on whether or not they have the same issue with the sustain pedal (It took a year before I noticed it on my own keyboard).

Finally, halfway between unweighted and fully weighted keyboards, you have half-weighted or semi-weighted keyboards.  I personally hate the action, but I hate it less than I hate unweighted keys.  I have successfully played somewhat intense classical pieces on them, and if it'll save a few hundred bucks on the cost of a new keyboard, it might be worth it.  When it comes to picking an action, make sure your wife plays it and likes how it feels; that really is the most important factor.  When I was buying a piano, my parents dragged me around to three or four warehouses full of pianos so that we could find one with an action that I liked.  (By the time I found a handful of good pianos, my fingers were very, very sore!)

Lastly, you'll need to choose the number of keys your keyboard will have.  Your choices will include 44, 61, 76, and 88 keys.  More keys means harder to move (my 88-key keyboard is depressingly close to as tall as I am), but also means less technically limiting.  That being said, I don't think that I've ever used all 88 keys on my keyboard at once.  I will reiterate, though, with a 61-key keyboard, you will eventually run out of keys and it will make practicing advanced pieces harder.

Make sure that you get a footswitch with your keyboard.  You will need them for pedaling on many, many pieces.  I don't believe that springing for a "piano-style" pedal will make a difference for beginners; it's mostly useful for half-pedaling, which is a technique that comes along later.  But there are a lot of inexpensive ones out there, so if you really want it, it won't hurt!

It sounds really obvious, but also make sure that your keyboard comes with its own speakers!  Some professional keyboards will not have built-in speakers; they assume that you're going to use a keyboard amp, and so putting onboard speakers would add weight and complexity unnecessarily.  To clarify, you really don't need a keyboard amp at this stage of the game, so steer away from these keyboards.

Good luck picking your keyboard.  If I've left something out, let me know!

Comment: For the number of keys, definitely go for 88 keys. This way, you are certain to be able to play the entire classical repertoire, except maybe for a couple of pieces composed for the rare 88+ keyboard.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the tips. I think getting her to try some out will be more important than I had considered. I had planned to just buy online, but I'll go and physically sample some before making a decision.

Comment: I'd imagine the shipping and handling on a fully weighted keyboard to be killer!  But it's fairly important to try the keyboards before buying; it's an investment that will stick with you for years!

Comment: @Babu @Anthony In the UK at least Amazon seems to offer free shipping on most, and both of these two are under 20kg: [Korg SP170](http://www.amazon.co.uk/KORG-SP170BK-SP170-DIGITAL-PIANO/dp/B002VO0F1W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309204900&sr=8-1) and [Yamaha P95B](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Yamaha-P95B-Digital-Portable-Piano/dp/B003MQLYM2/ref=pd_cp_MI_3). These are two I'm considering at the moment, but I'm going to find a shop and go and try them first.

Comment: The only slight amendment I would make is about the speakers - I know your wife is just starting but I haven't heard a piano with built-in speakers, even at the scary prices, that sounds any good.  I would rather go with the option of plugging into an existing hi-fi stereo or a fairly decent set of headphones, than miss out on all those deep juicy bass notes!  Failing that a half decent set of PC speakers should sound better than a lot of the built in ones. Otherwise it can be a little unsatisfying no matter how well you are playing.  Granted I am a bit of a snob about these things tho...

Comment: @Addsy the main reason I made that suggestion is that some speakerless keyboards will skip on a preamp, reasoning that an amplifier could do the job better.  The signal coming from these keyboards may not be very hot (for instance, a korg microstation that I frequently use will be drowned out by normal speaking when used with my 2.1 desktop speaker system).  In addition, the quality of the speakers varies from keyboard to keyboard; my portable grand's speakers are quite decent, even though they are blown away by a good monitor.

Comment: @Babu fair enuff.  Yeah I know I am generalising horribly by saying that all the on-board speakers are rubbish, maybe there are a few models out there with decent ones. I just find that if the sound that you are making is not satisying (or in the case of the worse offenders painfully tinny),  its hard to get excited about playing and that excitement is what its all about -  practice shouldn't be a job that needs to be done but rather a treat to be enjoyed!

Comment: One thing missing: make sure you like the default piano sound, because you'll living with it for a long while.

Comment: Babu, @Addsy: agreed, the price difference between pianos with and without built-in speakers is not very large (Yamaha produces often two models of the same piano, one without speaker and one without), implying that the amplifier and speakers are not expensive and thus the quality is not very good. One very important additional issue is in which direction these speakers point. Some keyboard have the speakers on the back side, so most users have the speakers directly against a wall. That does not help sound quality...

Comment: I'm considering a digital piano purely for space reasons.  Could you comment directly on how modern high-end models compare to a half-decent real piano, regarding sound and playability?  Your overview is great, I just need the comparative to convince myself it will be OK ... mentally I know I don't need perfect equivalence, but that's what I want! :P

Comment: Buying a professional digital piano designed for use on stage with a keyboard amplifier defeats the purpose of having a more compact instrument for home practice.  You can purchase an inexpensive cable that will allow you to use the headphone jack to plug the piano into a home stereo

Comment: I'd probably also advise against built-in speakers. $30 will get you some lovely headphones or you can use a spare HiFi.

Answer (score 12):

Considerations

- Touch sensitivity (this is a must)
- Number of keys you usually use
- Polyphony - the higher, the better if you play anything remotely complex
- Whether you need lots of sounds or really only piano sounds
- Size and weight if you plan on traveling with it.
- Built in drums/accompaniment or not (good for practice, more fun than a metronome)
- Built in speakers if you don't have an amp
- Quality, reputation of the maker and price

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good answer, but could be improved if you added some more detail to each item.

Answer (score 7):

Tim Praskins reviews ALL major models on his [Piano News Blog](http://azpianonews.blogspot.com), with a ton of information on "digital pianos and what to know when shopping for one".

From a recent (2011/08/17) entry:

> Yamaha has descriptive words such
>   as Intelligent Acoustic Control (IAC), GRE, Smooth Release, Linear
>   Graded Hammers, and Soundboard Speaker. Roland has SuperNATURAL Piano,
>   Kawai says Progressive Harmonic Imaging, and Kurzweil says Triple
>   Strike Piano. But for me as someone who has played hundreds of
>   different digital pianos over the years, words are meaningless because
>   at the end of the day, your enjoyment level will not be based on
>   words, but on reality instead.
>
> - Does the piano you purchased feel like and sound like a piano to you?
> - Does it make you happy when you play it and hear it?
> - Will it reproduce the kind of music you like when you play the piano?
>
> Those are the real questions that you need to ask when purchasing any
>   piano. Descriptive words used to define technologies and various
>   models do give you a point of reference, but you must judge a piano by
>   its own merit and not by the words used to describe it, that's all I'm
>   saying.
>
> One thing Roland and Kawai digital pianos offer this year is the
>   grand piano key action feature call "escapement or let-off." This is
>   the slight hesitation or notch as the key is depressed very gently
>   about 1/2 of the way down on a baby grand or grand. Roland and Kawai
>   have reproduced that feel in some of their nicer digital pianos
>   including the Roland HP302 (discount priced at $2499) and the Kawai
>   CN33 with synthetic ivory keys (discount priced at $2199), but Yamaha
>   has not done that on any of their digital pianos. I happen to like
>   that feature (I play acoustic baby grands quite often) and am
>   personally disappointed that Yamaha did not do that in any of their
>   digital pianos. Yamaha does advertise that the CLP440 (retail $3899,
>   discount priced about $3000) has "Real Grand Expression" (see display
>   specs below). Well honestly, that's not possible without the
>   escapement/let-off mechanism feature and Yamaha doesn't have that. If
>   you really want a "grand piano like feel" on a digital piano, you
>   gotta go to Roland or Kawai for that.

Answer (score 2):

For a beginning piano student you can get by with a less expensive digital piano made by Williams, Yamaha or Casio.  In order to better translate the feel to a real piano, you will want fully weighted keys that feel more like a real piano.  Don't fall for the semi weighted - and touch sensitive is not the same as weighted.  Since space is a concern, the lower priced home use models with built in speakers seem more practical than professional models requiring external amplification.  I am sure all digital pianos have headphone jacks which can also be used (with a cable available from most music or electronics stores) to play the piano through your home stereo or other external amplifier if you want to perform for an audience with better sound than the built in speakers provide.  At least 76 keys recommended in case your wife sticks with the lessons and starts learning more advanced arrangements.  88 keys is actually more common in digital pianos with weighted keys. All digital pianos I have seen have a sustain pedal jack and most include the pedal.  I have owned both lower priced Casio digital pianos and Yamaha and was happy with both.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

How many keys? 61 is definitely not enough. 76 will let you play most things, but not everything. Prokofiev's "Visions fugitives" goes right to the end of an 88 key piano.

How close does the key action come to a real piano? Best to ask an experienced player to try it.

How close does the sound come to a real piano? On a real piano, if the same key played piano then forte, forte is not just louder, it is a different sound. Your piano should have this, but without noticable "jumps" where slightly louder can sound a lot different.

Sound quality: How good are the built-in speakers? How much extra to get external speakers that make it sound like a good piano? Headphones sound quality?

Polyphony: If you are playing lots of notes at the same time, and there is not enough polyphony, notes will be dropped. Just disappear. 32 times should be the minimum (so four chords played with both hands don't drop notes).

Press the pedal, then play one note until the sound stops. It should sound natural until the end.

So far that is just replacing a mechanical piano with an electric one. For bonus points:

Is there more than one piano sound that is useful and not purely gimmicky?

Are there other *useful* sounds? (Organ, possibly different organ setups, xylophone / vibraphone)? If there are organ sounds, and you are serious about playing organ music, can you buy a foot pedal?

Automatic tuning? (That is not just well tempered, but adjusted to the key you're playing in.)

And finally: How heavy? Heavy is good if the piano stays in one place, but bad if you want to move it or even travel with it.